# What is the advantage of using .btn class inside a <div> vs inside a <button>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have code that's loosely based on the CSS of Bootstrap. One thing I did different is I placed the .btn class inside a button. However it seems like there are many times when the spacing is different and I cannot work out why.

Can anyone give me some advice here. Is it a nono to place the .btn inside a `<button>` element instead of a `<div>` when I am using all of the standard CSS for bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it permits to visually customize more your element when using a `div` (or an `a` tag) than when using a `button` tag since `button` tag has more associated attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely not wrapping the buttons with a `<div>` with the `.btn-group` class.

For example:

```
 <div class="btn-group">   
   <button class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>   
   <button class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
 </div>
```

There are many additional class modifiers you can add. Check out the component [button-group documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups%22%3ERight%3C/button%3E%20%3C/div%3E).

Times where you may not use the `<button>` element would be if you have `<a>` acting as a button in a `<ul>`, or in an HTTP Form where you'd want the `<input>` element to be the button.